# How to guarantee uniqueness of hash-based ID?

Tags: algorithm, hash, primary-key, unique

In database, uniqueness of PK is very important. And usually PK  is set as incremental integer or hash-based value. It's easy to know how to guarantee uniqueness of incremental integer, but I can't know how to guarantee uniqueness of hash-based values.

What is the popular, usual way to guarantee uniqueness of hash-based keys? Can you recommend some articles?

Comment: Why are you hashing: do you need cryptographic irreversibility of hashes, or just attempting to save space? Huffman coding is your perfect hash in the second case; nothing less *guarantees* uniqueness of hashes. Unless the PK data is somehow extremely sparse or somehow else peculiar, you could better build your PK clustered on the data itself. *That* will save space. Why would that be impossible? Can you tell a bit more about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a hash as opposed to a composite primary key? Otherwise, MD5 and SHA1 are usually the standards people use for hashing uniqueness. SHA1 has a slightly higher uniqueness value to it versus MD5 I've heard.